# How do I get nginx to issue 301 requests to HTTPS location, when SSL handled by a load-balancer?

Tags: nginx, ssl, load-balancing

I've noticed that there's functionality enabled in nginx by default, whereby a url request without a trailing slash for a directory which exists in the filesystem automatically has a slash added through a `301` redirect.

E.g. if the directory `css` exists within my root, then requesting `http://example.com/css` will result in a 301 to `http://example.com/css/`.

However, I have another site where the SSL is offloaded by a load-balancer. In this case, when I request `https://example.com/css`, nginx issues a 301 redirect to `http://example.com/css/`, despite the fact that the `HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO` header is set to `https` by the load balancer.

Is this an nginx bug? Or a config setting I've missed somewhere?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nginx doesn't look for HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO and it's not a bug. It's just lack of such functionality.

You should configure your frontend [to adjust the location header in responses](http://nginx.org/r/proxy_redirect), or replace it with another nginx (since nginx itself is a great load-balancer and SSL-terminator).

Comment: The problem in this case is that I don't control the load balancer. Personally, I feel that nginx knowing that the request came in on https and still issuing a redirect to a different protocol is a bug, but I can see how it might be a contentious issue. I'll contact the L/B manager and see what can be done.

Comment: No, nginx doesn't see. This header isn't defined by HTTP RFC, and even more this functionality isn't something that should be by default. See here why: http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/11/anatomy-of-attack-how-i-hacked.html (this is true for all X-Forwarded-* headers, web server should not blindly trust to any header received from client).

Answer (score 2):

Looks like the LB is doing SSL termination and nginx just gets a HTTP request. Nginx doesn't modify any of the HTTP headers it receives. You can do this using rewrite rules which checks whether HTTP_X_FORWARDED_PROTO is set or not and then accordingly rewrites the request. FYI nginx doesn't supported nested or complex "if" statements therefore you'll have to resort to the method described in the link below.

http://rosslawley.co.uk/2010/01/nginx-how-to-multiple-if-statements/